# OverflowError: math range error

Tags: python, математика

```
for i in range(len(out_text_2)-1):
      if i==0:
            out_text_2[i]=str(out_text_2[i])
      else:
           out_text_2[i]=str(int(int(out_text_2[i]1])+int(out_text_2[i]))%N) 
for i in range(len(out_text_2)-1):
           out_text_2[i]=str(int(pow(int(out_text_2[i]),e))%N)
```

Программа не может выполнять математические вычисления, т.к. в ответе получаются огромные числа.

Comment: Составьте вопрос нормально...

Comment: На какой строке возникает проблема?

Comment: в чём у вас вопрос? Уберите лишнее из кода: составьте минимальный самодостаточный пример. Опишите словами, что на входе, что вы хотите получить и что вместо этого происходит. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

При работе с очень большими числами стандартных типов не хватает. Вам нужно использовать модуль [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html).

Например, этот код вызывает исключение `OverflowError: math range error`:

```
from math import *
val = '9' * 200
print(pow(int(val), e))
```

Переписать его нужно так:

```
import decimal
from math import *
val = '9' * 200
# Указываем, сколько знаков после запятой (необязательно)
decimal.getcontext().prec = 50  
print(decimal.Decimal(val) ** decimal.Decimal(e))
```

Вывод:

```
4.5327909680335543398973100746569134091462672506017E+543
```

Comment: автору скорее всего следует с целыми  работать: `pow(10**200-1, 203, 2**32)` (вычисление степени по модулю).