# OverflowError: math range error при вычислении экспоненты

Tags: python, python-3.5

Выходит такая ошибка при вычислении экспоненты если на вход подавать значение `710` и выше. Как можно вычислить экспоненту в этом случае, даже с погрешностью?

```
>>> math.exp(710)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: math range error
```

Comment: И что говорит Google? `sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)`

Comment: Простите, мне эта строчка непонятна. Можно ли обойти это ограничение?

Comment: Можно, пренебрегая точностью

Comment: Спасибо. Как это сделать, как будет выглядеть эта функция?    

    `math.exp(710)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [OverflowError: math range error](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644370/overflowerror-math-range-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050907/python-overflowerror-math-range-error Мне кажется разумно обойтись выражением "стремится к нулю" или "стремится к бесконечности"

Comment: нужна цифра. Не хочется окружать код if

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо использовать более широкий тип с плавающей точкой. Например, можно использовать типы пакета `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
val = 711
print(np.exp(val, dtype=np.float128))
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. А можно это сделать без сторонних библиотек?

Comment: @Mavar, если только самому писать функцию вычисления экспоненты.